# Can't figure out this T_Variable error

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to activate a self-made wordpress plugin but am getting a T_Variable error on this line below.

```
type: "POST", url: "<?php$pluginDirectory = dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));?>/shoutbox.php", data: "action=insert&nick=" + nick + "&message=" + message,
                complete: function(data){
```

I'm having trouble figuring it out because I use the exact same php in another ajax call a few lines earlier but it doesn't trigger an error on plugin activation. This code's not triggering an error . Can anyone help?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "<?php$pluginDirectory = dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));?>/shoutbox.php", data: "action=update",
            complete: function(data){
                loading.fadeOut();
                messageList.html(data.responseText);
                messageList.fadeIn(2000);
            }
        });
    }
```

code that triggers an error

```
/*
Plugin Name: Shoutbox plugin
Plugin URI: http://www.blahblha.com/aboutmyplugin
Description: Shoutbox plugin
Author: Me!
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://www.blahblah.com
*/


function my_function {  ?>

$(document).ready(function(){
    //global vars
    var inputUser = $("#nick");
    var inputMessage = $("#message");
    var loading = $("#loading");
    var messageList = $(".content > ul");

//functions
function updateShoutbox(){
    //just for the fade effect
    messageList.hide();
    loading.fadeIn();
    //send the post to shoutbox.php
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", url: "<?php echo $pluginDirectory = dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));?>/shoutbox.php", data: "action=update",
        complete: function(data){
            loading.fadeOut();
            messageList.html(data.responseText);
            messageList.fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });
}
//check if all fields are filled
function checkForm(){
    if(inputUser.attr("value") && inputMessage.attr("value"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Load for the first time the shoutbox data
updateShoutbox();

//on submit event
$("#form").submit(function(){
    if(checkForm()){
        var nick = inputUser.attr("value");
        var message = inputMessage.attr("value");
        //we deactivate submit button while sending
        $("#send").attr({ disabled:true, value:"Sending..." });
        $("#send").blur();
        //send the post to shoutbox.php
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", url: "<?php echo $pluginDirectory = dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));?>/shoutbox.php", data: "action=insert&nick=" + nick + "&message=" + message,
            complete: function(data){
                messageList.html(data.responseText);
                updateShoutbox();
                //reactivate the send button
                $("#send").attr({ disabled:false, value:"Shout it!" });
            }
         });
    }
    else alert("Please fill all fields!");
    //we prevent the refresh of the page after submitting the form
    return false;
});
});

<?php

}   //this bracket is creating the same problem....

add_action('wp_head', 'my_function');
```

Comment: @OP: /offtopic: what do you expect `type: "POST", url: "<?php$pluginDirectory = dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__));?>` to do since it doesn't echo anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need a a space after `<?php` and before `$pluginDirectory`

Comment: that doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: It fixes the error, just still doesn't output anything. You might just be wanting to put `<?php echo dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__)); ?>`

Comment: o.k,sorry,  you're right. thanks. However, the closing bracket of the function (just before I add_action) is triggering the same type of error.  I updated OP with relevant code.. if you have an idea, please let me know. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Do you have an opening `<?php` tag somewhere before your first line you showed us (`function my_function {`). You should also change that line to `function my_function(){`

Comment: o.k, I added the opening php tag. The T_Errors are gone. Thanks a lot.